# Mostrar nombre de variable woocommerce en pre-visualizacion de producto

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

feliz día.
Sucede que me gustaría mostrar el nombre de las variaciones en el rango de producto que impone woo comerce :

[image: Ejemplo Variación]

Entonces en la imagen de arriba tengo dos variaciones, la de la izq llamada **x** y derecha **y**.

Buscando por los fichero del plugin encontré la función que trae estos valores con su clase llamada "amount".

```
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ), $price );
$return          = '<span class="amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';
```

Entonces, al momento de agregar el texto deseado que quiero que se muestre en las variaciones el resultado es que se va repetir en ambas variaciones.

```
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ), $price );
$return          = '<span class="amount"> X y Y' . $formatted_price . '</span>';
```

[image: después de editar]

Claro, ya con esto me di de cuenta es que estoy buscando por el lado equivocado. Ya que este cambio seria algo mas generico y no va directo al problema que es mostrar el nombre de las variaciones.

Por eso acudo a ustedes comunidad, si de pronto conocían en que archivo se pueda encontrar  la función de la variaciones o si conocen otro método para generar esto, obviamente cabe resaltar y ustedes me dirán si esto que quiero hacer es posible.

Muchas gracias.